# Comparing conditional means within a dataset

Tags: r, anova, mean, conditional-probability

I am attempting to find "the best" way to split a dataset. That is, I want to know what way to split the dataset, which subsequently will contain the most information.

I have several categorical variables over which I can split the dependent variable of interest. I know, I can split the data and perform ANOVA test for the different subsets, but that leaves me longing for a way to compare one split to another

I hope this makes sense. If more information is needed, please let me know

And just for the record: I will doing the work in R.

Comment: So, you want to split the data using the categorical variables (I assume they are the independent variables)? Have you considered some sort of clustering such as k-means? Or does it need to be based on "all observations within the same category should go to the same split"? I am not sure I fully understand your setting. The most information for what? For which variable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to make a model which predicts first period sales for different stores. For each store I have seven independent variables, which can all be used to build a model to predict sales. Normally I would build a traditional machine learning model, but of many of the categorical values I only have a small handful of observations, and so I was thinking of just starting to see what split contains the most information, i.e. help to predict sales better. Does it make sense?

Comment: So you have historical data on each store's seven characteristics (independent variables) and sales?

Comment: Yes, lots of stores have already opened I have the first month sales of them as well as all the categorical values.

Comment: I can't think of anything better than either iterating on the number of subsets and performing ANOVA each time, or iterating on the number of clusters and performing k-means or other clustering, or running some PCA or other dimensionality reduction to and see if you can visualize your independent variable space and see if there is a pattern of any sort?

Comment: Or, totally exploratory method - split the dependent variable (high-selling stores, low-selling stores or any other division you are trying to obtain) and analyze if any of the different independent variables are significantly different for each one of the subsets.